# Need a counter-example to disprove "If $X_n\rightarrow_d X$ and $Y_n\rightarrow_d Y$, then $X_nY_n\rightarrow_d XY$"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I know the following statement is wrong, but couldn't find a good counter-example.

"If $X_n\rightarrow_d X$ and $Y_n\rightarrow_d Y$, then $X_nY_n\rightarrow_d XY$"

where $\rightarrow_d$ means converge in distribution and $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are random variables.

Comment: Note that $X$ and $Y$ are not necesarrily defined on the same probability space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $X\sim\operatorname{Bin}(1,\tfrac 1 2)$, i.e. flip of a $0-1$ valued coin. Take $Y=1-X$, and $X_n=Y_n=X$ for all $n$. All these variables as well as the products $X_nY_n$ have the same distribution, but $XY$ is always $0$.

Comment: You mean $XY$ is always 0, right?

Comment: @Hank: Yes, fixed.